# How can I merge and add columns in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.

```
Seasons Frequency
DJF 1
JJA 10
MAM 20
SON 30
```

And

```
Seasons Frequency
DJF 1
JJA 10
MAM 20
SON 30
```

How can I merge these two dfs, at the same time adding the Frequency values?

Intended output:

```
Seasons Frequency
DJF 2
JJA 20
MAM 40
SON 60
```

Comment: Your feedback on different answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. Time difference and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using package `plyr`

```
require(plyr)
ddply(rbind(df1, df2), 
  .(Seasons), 
  summarize,
  Frequency=sum(Frequency))
```

Comment: This seems the most versatile of all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2 dataframes have identical structure, a one line code of base R will also do:

```
> df3 = data.frame(Seasons = df1$Seasons, Frequency = df1$Frequency+df2$Frequency)
> df3
  Seasons Frequency
1     DJF         2
2     JJA        20
3     MAM        40
4     SON        60
```

Comment: What is 'df1$Seasons' here?The code does not work: Error in df1$Seasons  : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 0):

If they're in order, with no missing labels, you can just add the second column.

```
df1$Frequency <- df1$Frequency + df2$Frequency)
```

If not, you can merge on the Seasons values, then add the two together and drop the extraneous column.

```
final.df <- merge(df1, df2, by='Seasons')
final.df$Frequency <- final.df$Frequency.x + final.df$Frequency.y
final.df$Frequency.x <- NULL
final.df$Frequency.y <- NULL
```